# How to make tooltips hide by clicking on them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

How can I make a tooltip never hide unless the actual tooltip is clicked on? Would a popover work better for this?

```
var Button = document.querySelector('.Button');

$(Button).attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
$(Button).attr("data-placement", "top");
$(Button).attr("title", "SHOWING TOOLTIP");

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 

if(status == true) {

        $(Button).tooltip('show');
        $(Button)
            .mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).tooltip('show');
            })
            .mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).tooltip('show');
            });
        $(Button).click(function() {
                console.log("clicked tooltip");
                $(this).tooltip('hide');
            });
    }
```

The reason I have the mouseenter and mouseleave methods is that is the only way I was able to have the tooltip permanently show.

The issue I am having is that if I click on the tooltip, it doesn't hide the tooltip, it actually just clicks on the button element. Is there anyway around this? The objective I am trying to achieve is that the tooltip should permanently show and then be hidden when the tooltip is clicked on.

EDIT: I am using Bootstrap for the tooltip along with jQuery.

Comment: What library are you using for the tooltip?

Comment: Where does the method `.tooltip()` come from?  Neither javascript nor jquery have a method named that.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap for the tooltip alongisde with jQuery.

Comment: You should probably keep the default behavior, since users are used to it, and to avoid breaking your page for visually disabled users that may be using a screen reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hookup a click event to hide it once the tooltip is shown...

```
$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
    $(".tooltip-inner").click(function(e){
        $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip("hide");
    });
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/6M28mCZHwE

If you *only* want the tooltip itself to hide the tooltip, change the data-trigger to `manual` and add a click handler to show the tooltip. This will prevent the trigger from hiding the tooltip.

```
$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').click(function(){
    $(this).tooltip("show");
});
```